# Hibernate Configuration does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, ant

I am really going crazy here. I have code like this:

```
private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

  Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  System.out.println("before");
  conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
  System.out.println("after");

  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties());       
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
  return sessionFactory;

}
```

I have set up the project in Eclipse with a src folder which contains packages and the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file. When I run the project using Eclipse the client gets the session fine (>before< and >after< are printed).

Now: I also have an Ant target to run my project and I am sure the hibernate.cfg.xml is in the classpath, but when I run the program the application does not print >after<. No exception there, but ultimately I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI`.

Anybody? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file was not in the right place. I enhanced my Ant script to copy the resource in the root of my classpath using the following target.

```
<target name="copy-resources">
    <copy todir="${targetdir}">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Configuration cf = new Configuration();

    //  cf.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
    cf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", datasourceJNDIName);


    cf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(cf.getProperties()).build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory  = cf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply kamel2005, but could you elaborate?

Comment: Okay, may you are missing  this property : cf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", datasourceJNDIName);                                                                              "datasourceJNDIName" String  is the jndi name as is in your server-side

Comment: the same for other mandatory properties  like username password driver class driver name and URL,